# Pulling ng-repeat array in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm using [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) and I can't find a way to pull the ng-repeat value to verify the data is populating.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products></div>
```

**PROTRACTOR TEST**

```
it( 'should load product data.', function() {
  auth(); //log in as user
  browser.get(server.dev + '/path').then(function(){
    var products = element.all(by.repeater('product in products'));
    console.log('products',products);
    expect( products.length >= 1 )
      .toBeTruthy();
    });
} );
```

The console shows an Element Array Finder not the data.

```
ElementArrayFinder {
  browser_: 
   ProtractorBrowser {
     actions: [Function],
     wait: [Function],
     sleep: [Function],
...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let the promise that element.all returns resolve first.

```
it( 'should load product data.', function() {
  auth(); //log in as user
  browser.get(server.dev + '/path').then(function(){
    var products = element.all(by.repeater('product in products')).then(function(products){
        console.log('products',products);
        expect( products.length >= 1 ).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

Found in the Protractor docs HERE: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder

Answer (score 2):

You can also use element.all().count() to get the number of elements found for the given selector, look at the below code

```
it( 'should load product data.', function() {
  auth(); //log in as user
  browser.get(server.dev + '/path').then(function(){
     var products = element.all(by.repeater('product in products'))
     expect(products.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: This should actually be an accepted answer here. No need to resolve the promise here explicitly.